# Find files with grep and open in editor

Tags: bash, vim, emacs, grep

I'd like to use `grep` for searching through a directory and open the files with matches in an editor of choice. (emacs or vim will do.)

I can open the first match via `vim $(\grep -l "static void main" *)`, but this won't open the other matching files. The `\` in front of grep is used to use an unmodified grep, usually I have colored grep which will not work because it leads to wrong filenames.

I am aware that I can try `find`, pipe the results each to grep and open then the file found in question each in a new editor, with the help of `xargs`.

---

**Best working solution**:

*USAGE*: 
`grepe static void main` or
 `grepv static void main`.

No `""` needed.

*INSTALL*:
Put this into your `.bashrc`.

```
#emacs:
grepe(){
    emacs $(\grep -irl "$*" .)
}
#vim:
grepv(){
    vim $(\grep -irl "$*" .)
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I think you would need `find -type f | xargs grep -l 'static void main' | xargs vim` but it sounds like that's not what you want...

Comment: Also opens just one file. But issues error `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`.

Comment: It opens multiple files if there are multiple matches...

Comment: It's smarter to list the result and let you choose which file to open in your editor.

Comment: How about fixing that up in bash and giving a new answer, @CodyChan ?

Comment: @sjas try https://github.com/facebook/PathPicker

Comment: i'm not exactly keen on installing some github crap on servers. this is not about some dev workstation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `**` in the file pattern to search recursively. For example, to search for all lines containing `dostuff()` in all `.c` files in the parent directory and all its subdirectories, use:

```
:vimgrep /dostuff()/ ../**/*.c
```

Read more @ http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

For an editor independent way, try

```
vim -o $(grep -rl string directory)
```

Comment: I am looking for a editor-independent solution, if possible. Not just for vim. Thanks, still. :)

Comment: Glad it helped especially since I wrote it on my mobile :-)

Answer (score 4):

For Emacs you would typically perform the find/grep inside Emacs.

e.g. use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep`

The results are then processed by Emacs and you can easily jump to any result.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are not specifying the search path after the pattern. 

For the simplest method:

```
vim $(grep -l "static void main" *)
```

For the smarter one (doesn't open Vim unless there were any results):

```
files=$(grep -l "static void main" *) && vim $files
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Pipe the output of grep to `| sed 's/.*/"&"/'` to escape annoying file names.

Comment: I personally think running it recursively in the current directory is the most versatile variant of it.
`files=$(grep -irl "static void main" .) && vim $files`

Answer (score 2):

for other editor (like sublimetext `subl`) I use to do that:

```
grep ... -l | xargs subl
```

the `-l` will only display the path so then you can directly open with your editor if it has command line support

Comment: Thank you! This helped me implement a variant with the [faster `ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep#quick-examples-comparing-tools): 

```shell
rg  --null  --color=never  --files-with-matches …search…term… | xargs $EDITOR
```